# Error in accessing MySQL using RODBC in opensuse

Tags: mysql, database, opensuse

I have installed R 2.13 in opensuse 11.04. I wanted to access a MySQL db using R. I Installed RODBC without any error. I can even load the RODBC (`usinglibrary('RODBC')`). 
When I tried to connect to db using

```
library(RODBC)
channel = odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=myserver;Database=db;User=me;Password=***;", readOnlyOptimize = TRUE)
```

It says,

Warning messages:

```
1: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=server;Database=bd;User=me;Password=abcd;",  :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=server;Database=db;User=me;Password=abcd;",  :
  ODBC connection failed
```

How do I solve this ?